# Stored Functions: How to add multiple varchar together?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, stored-functions

I try to get two varchar into one with a mysql Stored Functions?

Like with php ($ var1. $ var2) or javascript´s (var1 + var2)

It does not seem that it works with plus(p_email+p_password).

```
DELIMITER $$

DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS `voidcod_eventgroup`.`dummy`$$
CREATE FUNCTION `voidcod_eventgroup`.`dummy` (
     p_email VARCHAR(300),
     p_password VARCHAR(16)
) RETURNS VARCHAR(316)
BEGIN
     /* this only returns p_password NOT p_email*/
     RETURN p_email+p_password;

END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Greeting Voidcode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try to use CONCAT, haven't tried it for this kinda stuff though :)

```
CONCAT(p_email, p_password);
```

Comment: I think it's CONCAT(p_email, p_password)